# Quiz show contestant

Tags: probability

A contestant on a quiz show is presented with two questions, questions 1 and 2, which he is to attempt to answer in some order he chooses.

If he decides to try question $i$ first, then he will be allowed to go on to question , $j$ (if $i, j \in \{1, 2\}$, $i \neq j$), only if his answer to question $i$ is correct.

If his initial answer is incorrect, he is not allowed to answer the other question.

The contestant is to receive $V_i$, dollars if he answers question $i$ correctly, $i \in \{1,2\}$. For instance, he will receive $V_1 + V_2$ dollars if he answers both questions correctly.

If the probability that he knows the answer to question $i$ is $P_i$ which question should he attempt to answer first so as to maximize his
expected winnings?

Assume that the events $E_i$ (event he chooses question $i$ as the first question), that he knows the answer to
question $i$ are independent events.

I understand this question completely except in the example in the book it shows that:

$$E[E_1] = V_1(P_1)(1-P_2) = V_2(P_2)(1-P_1) = E[E_2]$$

Which represents the expected value of choosing question 1 first being equivalent to the expected value of the person choosing question 2 first

The contestant should:
Choose question 1 first

I do not understand why if they are equal question 1 is the better choice. I am missing something?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Two criticisms of your question: [1] Please proofread your question, after posting, to see if it will be crystal clear to the reader.  For example, what does this mean: "...then he will be allowed to go on to question , j7 i"?  That is, what does "j7 i" signify?  [2].  Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to format the math in your question.

Comment: Apologies, I copied the text from a picture and didn't realize it copied incorrectly. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to follow the analysis in the answer.  Here is my approach:

Let $E_k$ denote the expectation, assuming that question $k$ is attacked first.

Let $~~Q_1 = 1 - P_1, ~~Q_2 = 1 - P_2.$

Then

$$E_1 = (P_1Q_2)V_1 + (P_1P_2) (V_1 + V_2).$$

$$E_2 = (P_2Q_1)V_2 + (P_1P_2) (V_1 + V_2).$$

So, the choice of best strategy simplifies to a comparison of

$$(P_1Q_2)V_1 ~~\text{versus} ~~(P_2Q_1)V_2.$$